# Iterative Variable Value Assignment in For Loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck with a VBA code and badly need your help. Here's what I am trying to achieve -

Step 1 : I have to iteratively capture strings in column D (the count of which is mentioned in C2 which will change depending on the data set)

Step 2 : Each of these strings will be split based on "_" and I have to re-combine them since I only need the 2nd, 1st, 3rd, 5th part (in that particular order) - represented further down in column D under 'Output'

Step 3 : I have to join the newly made string in column D and strings in column F and create all possible combinations - represented further down in column F under 'Output'

Step 4 : Supply all created combinations to range C in a different sheet (stuck at this step) :(

Below is the code I was trying to create, which for some reason is not looping through i. It just keeps giving me value 4. Is it because we can't dynamically assign and flush values of variables in a loop? temp_string in my case. I have tried all the other varieties of loop but no help. I think I am fundamentally missing something here. Any advise is highly appreciated!

```
Sub Test()
Dim a_count As Integer, i As Integer
Dim temp_string As String, temp_substring As String
Dim o_array() As String

a_count = Sheet7.Range("C2")

For i = 2 To a_count
   temp_string = Sheet7.Range("D" & i)
   o_array = Split(temp_string, "_")
   temp_substring = o_array(1) & "_" & o_array(0) & "_" & o_array(2) _
   & "_" & o_array(4)
Next i

Debug.Print i, temp_substring
End Sub
```

[image: Input & Output]

Comment: Your `DEBUG` is outside the loop so it's running through the entire loop and printing the final value to the immediate window.  Put `Debug.Print i....` just before `Next i`.

Comment: What is the value in range `C2`?  If it's less than 2 then I guess the loop won't run at all, if it's equal to 2 it will loop just the once.... _I think_.

Comment: Good lord *facepalm*! Thank you so much @DarrenBartrup-Cook! :)

Comment: Hey @DarrenBartrup-Cook! There's further guidance I need on this piece. I was able to recreate the iterations using for loops. For example, the 6 variations in Column F 'Output' as stored in 2D array temp(1,1), temp(1,2), temp(2,1), temp(2,2), temp(3,1) and temp(3,2). But I need to assign these values one by one in the range G, for example. A third loop is conflicting with the two loops because the number of iterations are varying because of a third variable. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is the code I am using
For j = 1 To adset_count
    For k = 1 To creative_count
        iet_string = Sheet7.Range("D" & j + 1)
        oet_array() = Split(iet_string, "_")
        assub_string = oet_array(2) & "_" & oet_array(3) & "_" & oet_array(4) & "_" & oet_array(5) & "_" & oet_array(6) & "_" & oet_array(7)
        ic_string = Sheet7.Range("F" & k + 1)
        a_string = csub_string & "_" & assub_string & "_" & ic_string
        temp(j, k) = a_string
Debug.Print j, k, temp(j, k)
    Next k
Next j

'Columns may vary as this is referencing to the final data set. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim a_count As Long
    Dim iet As Range
    Dim fet As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rCell1 As Range
    Dim array_size As Long
    Dim o_Array() As String
    Dim o_FinalOutput() As String
    Dim temp_substring As String
    Dim x As Long

    With Sheet7

        'Change so it returns the last row with data, not the count of data.
        a_count = .Range("C2")
        'or
        'a_count = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

        'These two variables will reference the full range of figures
        'in column D and column F.
        Set iet = .Range("D4", .Cells(a_count, 4))
        Set fet = .Range("F4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))

    End With

    'Figure out the size of the final array.
    array_size = iet.Cells.Count * fet.Cells.Count
    ReDim o_FinalOutput(1 To array_size)

    'Step through each cell in column D.
    For Each rCell In iet
        o_Array = Split(rCell, "_")
        temp_substring = o_Array(1) & "_" & _
                         o_Array(0) & "_" & _
                         o_Array(2) & "_" & _
                         o_Array(4) & "_"

        'Step through each cell in column F and stick it to column D text.
        For Each rCell1 In fet
            x = x + 1
            o_FinalOutput(x) = temp_substring & rCell1
        Next rCell1

    Next rCell

    'Dump the whole array into Sheet2 starting at cell C1.
    With Sheet2
        .Range("C1", .Cells(array_size, 3)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(o_FinalOutput)
    End With

End Sub
```

You may want to read up on [Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells) which is basically the same as `Range` except it looks at a single cell and uses row and column numbers.

You'll also need to adjust some figures to put data on the correct rows.

**E.g.**
`.Range("C1", .Cells(array_size, 3))` - `array_size` will only work if you're starting on row 1. To start on row 2 you'll need to add 1 to the array_size:  `.Range("C2", .Cells(array_size+1, 3))`

Comment: This is great @Darren Bartup-Cook! Thank you so much for your help :)